# AndroidJunit4 runner logging

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am writing instrumentation tests for my application and today I had an issue when the view that had to be clicked was outside the screen. Unfortunately the only thing I saw in the logs was the following:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click' on view 'Animations or transitions are enabled on the target device.
```

Which was definitely not the actual error.

I have wrapped the test body with `try-catch` and used `Log.e` to dump the actual exception. Reading logcat I could see the full stacktrace and found that any kind of exception shows like this when the test is executed using gradle.

I think that the test runner is catching the actual exception and dumps only that generic message. But I failed to find any way to change that behavior.

Running gradle with `--stacktrace` or `--full` doesn't help - it only shows the exception as seen outside the emulator.

So how do I actually see what is the problem without the workaround I used (catching the exception myself, dumping it, reading logcat)?